# There exists strictly increasing $\{x_n\}$ that converges to $\sup E$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I need to prove that, if $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a non-empty bounded set and $\sup E \not\in E$ then there exists a strictly increasing sequence $\{x_n\}$ that converges to $\sup E$ such that $x_n \in E$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I've been trying to find a clue in the textbook, but couldn't. I don't even know how to start the proof. Could someone please give a clue?

Comment: Hint. There must be some sequence in $E$ approaching $\sup E$. Can you prove it has an increasing subsequence?

Comment: @EthanBolker: I think that the very concept which is needed to be proved is that there exists a sequence converging to $\sup E$, not its subsequence.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Firstly, choose any element $x_1 \in E$. As stated, $\sup E \notin E \implies x_1 < \sup E$. Using the approximation property for suprema, for each $n \geq 2 \exists x_n \in E$ such that $\max(\sup E -\frac{1}{n},x_{n-1})<x_n<\sup E$ so that a sequence $x_1<x_2<x_3<...$ is strictly increasing.

Then go on to apply the Squeeze theorem and you should be home and dry.

**Edit** Show that the sequence above is increasing

Start at $n=1$ there exists an $x \in E$ such that $\sup  E  − 1 < x$. Denote this $x = x_1$. Now, for $n=2$ there exists an $x \in E$ such that $\sup E − \frac{1}{2}  < x_2$. Clearly $x_2 > x_1$. This works for any $n$ so there exists a sequence $x_n \in E$ with the property that $\sup E - \frac{1}{n}<x_{n}$

Comment: It's not clear why there must exist a sequence satisfying $\max(\sup E - \frac{1}{n}, x_{n-1}) < x_n$. How can we be sure it does exist?

Comment: @sequence I think it hinges on the notion that if $\sup E$ exists, then by the approximation property for suprema, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an element $x_{i}$ such that $x_{i}>\sup E - \varepsilon$.

Comment: But how can we be sure that this is valid for each $n\ge 2$, and that if $\max(\sup E- \frac{1}{n}, x_{n-1}) \ne x_{n-1}$ then how can we conclude that $x_{n}$ is strictly increasing?

Comment: @sequence See edit to my answer for further info - it was too long for a comment.

Comment: I think that if $x_1 > \sup E - 1$ and $x_2 > \sup E - \frac{1}{2}$ then this does not necessarily imply that $x_2 > x_1$. For example, if $\sup E = 5$, then $x_1 := 4.7 > \sup E - 1 = 4$ and $x_2 := 4.6 > \sup E - \frac{1}{2} = 4.5$, but $x_2 < x_1$. @Bacon

Comment: @sequence Hmmn, early in the morning here but can't your counterexample be explained away via the Monotone Convergence Theorem (Lemma 1 in wiki link)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lemma_1

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm just trying to understand your proof, and I see that there are still questions about it. @Bacon

Comment: @sequence Yes, apologies, that's not helpful. Ok, I've thinking about this; what about approaching it by saying that for $b=\sup E$, with $n$ any positive number. Clearly $b-\frac{1}{n}$ is not an upper bound of $E$ so $\exists$ some $b_n \in S$ such that $b \geq b_n \geq b-\frac{1}{n}$ - So by implication $b_n$ converges to $b$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** $E\cap(\sup E-x_{n-1},\sup E]$ is not empty.

Comment: I'm not sure how this can help :(

Comment: This made me wonder: Is there a proof that doesn't use the axiom of choice?

Comment: Indeed, this is a very good hint.

Comment: I'm not sure what use is such a terse hint (to the point of being hardly understandable, see OP's comment) when there are other, more detailed hints. It's the kind of hint that's only helpful if you already know the solution and can say "yeah, that's how it's done indeed". Oh well.

Comment: @Farnight I'm no expert, but in general it seems hard to construct any kind of sequence without the [axiom of dependent choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice) (which is weaker than the axiom of choice).

Comment: The OP states "I don't even know how to start the proof. Could someone please give a clue?" This is one clue.

Answer (score 0):

I'll turn my hint into an answer.

Start with a sequence $x_n$ in $E$ converging to $\sup E$. No element of that sequence can be greater than or equal to all the ones that follow, since $\sup E$ is not in $E$, so you can construct an increasing subsequence inductively: when you have chosen $L$ elements the last of which is some $x_k$, find an $x_n > x_k$ with $n > $k.

That increasing subsequence has the same limit as the original sequence, so you're done.

Answer (score -2):

I would phrase a hint as this:

**If there were no sequence approaching $\sup E$, how could $\sup E$ be the supremum?**

Comment: The point is that the sequence in question must be strictly increasing. For example there is no strictly increasing sequence (in $E$) converging to the sup of $E = \{1\}$. Your hint is not helpful at all in this regard.

Comment: I see. But since it is assumed that $\sup E\notin E$, the hint still applies.